# Не получается загрузить файл Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

В HTTP-запросе через `form-data` передаю файл.

Вот так вот его обрабатываю:

```
file = request.data['file']
Product.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(photo=file)
return Response({'id': pk, 'file': file.name})
```

Название файла добавляется в модель в поле `photo`, а в папку с изображениями не помещается.

Как сделать так, чтобы полученный файл добавлялся в медиа-папку?

Поле в модели:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Папка `images` находится в корне проекта на одном уровне с папкой приложения.

Через `Django Admin` все отрабатывает корректно, фото помещается в медиа-папку, но при помощи запроса с `form-data` почему-то не работает..

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, заменив строку

```
Product.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(photo=file)
```

На вот такое:

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
product.photo = file
product.save()
```

Вот только непонятно почему именно, вроде бы тоже самое, поле обновляется файлом, но в первом случае не происходит запись в медиа-папку, а во втором происходит.